# ?How to add custom button to UIPopoverController

Tags: iphone, ipad

How to add button to UIPopoverController ?

I am attaching a picture for able to understand very clear.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
    UIViewController* popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc] init]; 
    UIView *popoverView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    UIToolbar *toolbar=[[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,400 ,44)];
    toolbar.barStyle =UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
    NSMutableArray *ButtonArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc ]init];
    Save=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc ]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(save_pressed)];
    UIBarButtonItem *space=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *cancel=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc ]initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancel_pressed)];

    [ButtonArray addObject:cancel];
    [cancel release];   
    [ButtonArray addObject:space];
    [space release];
    [ButtonArray addObject:Save];
    [Save release];
    [toolbar setItems:ButtonArray];
    [ButtonArray release];
    [popoverView addSubview:toolbar];
    [toolbar release];
    picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    picker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 400, 340);
    picker.delegate  = self;
    picker.dataSource = self;
    picker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    [popoverView addSubview:picker];
    popoverContent.view = popoverView;
    popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];
    [popoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(400, 264) animated:NO];
    [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:btn.frame inView:scr_AddLocation permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
    [popoverView release];
    [popoverContent release];
here I m adding Picker To Popover When We Pressed Button .
```

Answer (score 0):

The cancel button (if that is what you are referring to) is the `rightBarButtonItem` of the `UINavigationController`'s navigation bar. You can set it to be a standard `UIBarButtonItem` (as is done here) or a custom one (whose view you can create).

Comment: @ Akshay  Yes Its referring to cancle button ... What the HTH?